# How to extract unique values from a data frame in r

Tags: r

I would like to extract the unique values from this data frame as an example

```
test <- data.frame(position=c("chr1_13529", "chr1_13529", "chr1_13538"),
               genomic_regions=c("gene", "intergenic", "intergenic"))
```

The resulting data frame should give me only

```
chr1_13538      intergenic
```

Basically I want to extract rows that have a unique position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R approach:

There are two parts:

1. We create a list of positions that occur at least twice using `duplicated`
2. We look for positions that are not in the list of duplicated positions

Then we subset `test` on condition 2.

```
test[!test$position %in% test$position[duplicated(test$position)],]
#    position genomic_regions
#3 chr1_13538      intergenic
```

Comment: This also worked! I knew about the `duplicated` function, but was missing part 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse`/`dplyr` solution.

You are just grouping by `position`, counting occurances, and selecting those that only have 1 occurance.

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  group_by(position) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  filter(count == 1) %>%
  select(-count)
```